# Construct a type from keys of another type

Tags: typescript

I have an object '`content`' that is using a generic interface for data models.

I'm trying to create a type guard that will validate that my content object includes certain valid keys.

However, after performing a type guard, the `content` object can still contain the fields that were omitted. Ideally, I could construct a new type from the Generic interface I'm using with only the keys I pass as valid properties.

Is this kind of approach possible?

Sandbox for example

https://codesandbox.io/s/determined-golick-m0x66d?file=/src/index.ts

Comment: Please put your example code as plaintext within the question itself; an external link is a nice supplement but isn't sufficient to be considered a [mre].

Comment: Does [this approach](https://tsplay.dev/wEBevN) meet your needs? The new type needs to be narrower than the existing type, so it has to be something like `{id: number, title: number, description?: string}` where `description` is still optional (and not *gone* from the type).  Anyway, if that works for you I can write up an answer; if not, what am I missing? (Please mention @jcalz in your reply to notify me)

Answer (score 1):

Keep in mind TypeScript gets compiled to JavaScript before execution. That means you cannot create types from runtime information like the list of strings you pass to `validateSchemaData`. What you could do is just delete the properties, that are not given in the `requiredKeys`.